# HTML como bloquear campos

Tags: php, html, css

Quiero saber si hay alguna forma de que un input arroje opciones para seleccionar, pero solo eso, que no se pueda escribir denro de este campo
Alguien sabe como?

Comment: ¿Hablas de un `<select>`?

Comment: Si, solo quiero que puedan esoger lo que hay dentro y no escribir

Answer (score 0):

No utilices un `<input>`, utiliza un `<select>`:

```html
<label for="carro">Seleccione una marca de carro:</label>

<select name="carro" id="carro">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Más información: [tag *select*](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp) (en inglés)